# How to find a javascript function using selenium/python/chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

Im struggling to find and click javascript element which inspected looks like this:

```
"<a href="javascript:setTopicMode('PAAdvanced-search','300')">Patch advisories</a>"
```

I tried to find by name, partial name and a href but I am a beginner so I did not managed to make it work.

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onlick*=PAAdvanced-search','300]").click();` does not work either

Can someone advise?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the URL? maybe you have to switch into a frame

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to click on above mentioned link then find that using text.
Use `//a[text()='Patch advisories']` xpath :

```
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Patch advisories']")
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something simple like

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Patch advisories").click()
```

An alternative using the href would be to do something like

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='PAAdvanced-search']").click()
```

If those aren't working, something else is going on in the page. You either need a wait to wait for them to be available or you may have an `IFRAME` on the page.